# How to assign an image to all the 12 faces of a Dodecahedron

Tags: graphics3d, image-processing, textures

How do i assign an image to all of the 12 faces of a Dodecahedron?

Comment: possible duplicate [Modify each version of the polyhedron with an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198780/125)

Comment: Related: [(63655)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63655), [(110295)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110295).
Also  [(55218)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55218),
[(38656)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38656)