# How to get the faces of d20 in order

Tags: polyhedra

You can get the faces of an icosahedron with:

```
PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "FaceIndices"]
```

This gives:

```
{2, 12, 8}, {2, 8, 7}, {2, 7, 11}, {2, 11, 4}, 
 {2, 4, 12}, {5, 9, 1}, {6, 5, 1}, {10, 6, 1}, 
 {3, 10, 1}, {9, 3, 1}, {12, 10, 8}, {8, 3, 7}, 
 {7, 9, 11}, {11, 5, 4}, {4, 6, 12}, {5, 11, 9}, 
 {6, 4, 5}, {10, 12, 6}, {3, 8, 10}, {9, 7, 3}
```

But I need the faces in an order consistent with a d20 die. E.g.

[image]

Is it possible to persuade Mathematica to provide this?

Comment: The answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55218/9490) may be useful

Comment: Yes, thank you.